# How do I center this div element?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following HTML and CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/64vUR/

**Relevant CSS**

```
 .content {
    position: absolute;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I need to have the three columns horizontally centered and despite my best efforts including looking at other similar questions on this site, I can't figure it out. Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/64vUR/2/) what you want?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not quite understanding what you are trying to do. Do you want each of these on their own row, or all of them in one row?

Comment: I believe the OP wants the `.content` div horizontally centered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/64vUR/4/)

Remove

```
.pricing-table {
    float: left;
}
```

And add

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
}
.pricing-table {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

The problem with `inline-block` is that spaces in HTML separate elements, so even having `width: 48.9%` you won't have two elements one next to other because that extra space.

You can solve that with html comments wrapping newlines and indentation, or with `font-size: 0` to parent and resetting it to each column.

In your case, since you already had a custom `font-size`, you can use

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.pricing-table {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/64vUR/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for this, works great.

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64vUR/5/)